# Average Case Complexity of a function

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

What is the **[average case complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity)** of the following function given that the input is a set of independent uniform natural numbers.

```
def d(a):    
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == 0 or a[i] == 1:
            for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
                if not (a[j] == 0 or a[j] == 1):
                    swap(a, i, j)
                    break
```

What do you think, how to approach this problem in mathematical terms?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without specifying the distribution of the input numbers.

Comment: "random"(uniformly distributed) natural numbers is not enough?

Comment: No. Distribued between what and what? Are those numbers independent or not?

Comment: Ok I must admit I have lack of information here. When I say random natural number set, what I mean is that the set is independent, uniform set of numbers starting from 0 to infinity. No sure how to express this with a well math. vocabulary?

Comment: If that's the case, then the probability of the inner execution of the loop is zero, so it's trivially O(n).

Comment: @Sumer Cip It's already expressed correctly. Well, you might have said "a list of independently identically distributed randomly chosen elements of ℕ(with a uniform distribution/each with equal probability)", but one could infer that from "random", which is a shorthand for the above.

Comment: @phihao: "random" is certainly not a synonym for "random with uniform distribution", esp. since a uniform distribution over the natural numbers cannot exist without some maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving out all the details, we get two nested loops, indicating a quadratic algorithm. Taking the `if` into account, such a small percentage of numbers actually execute the inner loop that the average case is effectively linear.

Comment: Beware! Even if the probability is 0.0000001%, the average complexity is still O(n²): asymptotic complexity doesn't take into account how "tiny" constants are.

Comment: @akappa: the probability of a 0 or a 1. But now that I think about it, the OP should have specified a distribution over natural numbers.

Comment: @akappa: That's not entirely true. Just for example, if code can only execute log(N) percent of the time, you get a logarithmic complexity. In this case, the OP's statement was "random natural numbers", which means probability of executing the inner loop is 0, and we get linear complexity. You're assuming non-zero probability of executing the inner loops, which would be correct only for a finite range of inputs (though for anything on a computer, the range must be finite, of course).

Comment: @larsmans: that's the point, he left the probability distribution unspecified. But I think it's realistic to assume that the distribution doesn't depend upon n (i.e., he gets a stream of random, independent, identically distributed numbers).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: what kind of probability distribution function would induce the inner loop to execute O(log n) times?

Comment: @akappa - assuming he meant a uniform distribution then the probability of a[i] being a 0 or a 1 is 0 (2/inf).  So the answer is that it's linear.

Comment: I'm not saying any would in this case, I'm saying that such possibilities exist. All he's said in this case is that the inputs are random natural numbers, giving 0 probability of executing the inner loop. The range of natural numbers is infinite, and he's given a finite set that executes the inner loop. n/infinity=0 for any finite n.

Comment: @Niki: I'm with you. I've assumed he has a probability distribution over integers in the range [0, k], because it makes more sense.

Comment: @akappa: How is it sensible to impose a limit on the size of numbers, but not on the size of the array?

Comment: @Niki: a uniform distribution over an infinite set cannot exist.

Comment: @larsmans: an infinite set cannot exist, except as a concept. If you're willing to accept the concept of an infinite set, it's not much of a leap to the concept of any member of the set having any of its values with equal probability.

Comment: @Jerry: infinite sets are perfectly acceptable mathematical objects, but uniform distributions on them are not. See any good book on probability or information theory. (The problem is that the probabilities become infinitesimal, or the entropy infinite.)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(a)):
```

The result will be the length of `a` multiplied with the average time for any index in `range(len(a))` (let's ignore the `break` for now).

```
if a[i] == 0 or a[i] == 1:
```

Two accesses of the values of `a`, so let's add `2 * [time to retrieve a[i]]`. The probability that a value of `a`(an element of an infinite set, ℕ) is an element of any finite set(such as {0,1}) is infinitely close to zero. Since the further code inside takes finite time, we can safely ignore it.

Average case complexity: `2 len(a) [time to retrieve a[i]]` ∈ `Θ(len(a))` ⊂ `O(len(a))`.

Comment: @larsmans No, the distribution of values of `a` does not depend on its length. For example, [42] is a valid input.

Comment: how can you say? We doesn't know anything about P(a = v), where v is a vector of numbers.

Comment: @akappa We do know. We know the length of `a` and know each of its members is a random element of ℕ, which is an infinite set. The probability to draw a specific element of an infinite set is zero, therefore the probability of drawing multiple specific elements (i.e. v) is zero.